# Webpack & Bower: Multiple css & js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bower, webpack

I'm just getting started with Webpack (for use w/ React), and I'm running into an issues when trying to pull in bower packages. I have installed [pickadate](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js) through bower and I have the following webpack config ([original](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/webpack/dev.config.js)). Looking at the pickadate bower.json file, it has an array instead of just a string for `main` as it needs to pull in multiple js and css files.

```
// ./webpack/dev.config.js
// ...
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: [
    'src',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components'
  ],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    )
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.json', '.js']
},
```

My Component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

import $ from 'jquery';
import pickadate from 'pickadate';

class DateInput extends Component {
  // ...
}
```

I get the following errors for jquery and pickadate modules:

```
@ ./src/components/forms/DateInput.js 17:14-31
[0] ./src/components/forms/DateInput.js
[0] Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/components/forms
[0] resolve module jquery in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/components/forms
[0]   looking for modules in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src
[0]     /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/jquery doesn't exist (module as directory)
[0]     resolve 'file' jquery in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src
[0]       resolve file
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/jquery doesn't exist
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/jquery.json doesn't exist
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/jquery.js doesn't exist

// ...

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'pickadate' in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/components/forms
[0] resolve module pickadate in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/components/forms
[0]   looking for modules in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src
[0]     /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/pickadate doesn't exist (module as directory)
[0]     resolve 'file' pickadate in /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src
[0]       resolve file
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/pickadate doesn't exist
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/pickadate.json doesn't exist
[0]         /Users/chris7519/Desktop/react-redux-universal-hot-example/src/pickadate.js doesn't exist
```

I attempted to install both jquery and pickadate through npm, but I still get the error `Cannot find module 'pickadate'`

Answer (score 2):

The pickadate module on npm has a broken `package.json` file: it doesn't specify a main entry, so webpack has no idea how to resolve `require('pickadate')`. You should probably file an issue upstream for them to fix this, but in the meanwhile you can fix it in your `webpack.config.js`.

So, you want to install both pickadate and jquery through npm, and then add the following to `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'pickadate' : 'pickadate/lib/picker',
        },
    },
 }
```

This basically treats all instances of `require('pickadate')` into `require('pickadate/lib/picker')`. This reaches into the pickadate package and actually requires a real file. If upstream fixes their `package.json` to have a main entry, you can delete this alias from your config and all your requires will work properly.

More information about how the alias option works: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

Comment: I gave this a try, but I'm still getting an error stating that it cannot find module 'pickadate'

Comment: Does it work if you require pickadate/libs/picker (i.e. is it the alias that's not working?)

Answer (score 0):

The `webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin` doesn't handle bower.json description file when the 'main' field is an array, for example [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json):

```
"main": [
"less/bootstrap.less",
"dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

In that case, you should install the package using npm, and require() css files explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using a pickadate wrapper (ng-pickadate), hopefully most of the quirks will apply:

- Referencing the js files, pickadate package json entry point seems not to be ok.
- Disabling AMD for the pickadate node modules path.
- Add providepluing ($, Jquery, window.jquery).

Bellow the step by step guide (remove the angular part, if you just want to configure pickadate).

Following the steps mentioned in this thread, I manage to make it work without having to tweak the code under node_modules. Just a quick recap (angular 1, webpack 2 solution):

First install ng-pickadate

`npm install ng-pickadate`

> It will download as well jquery and pickadate dependencies.

Then we need to add the depencies in our webpack.config, here there's a catch  *pickadate.js* package json main seems not to be pointing to the right entry point, we have to manually indicate which files we want to include:

`diff
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(basePath, 'src'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  entry: {
    app: './app/app.ts',
    vendor: [
+      'jquery',
+      'angular',

+      'pickadate/lib/picker',
+      'pickadate/lib/picker.date',

+      'ng-pickadate',
    ],`

Now comes fun part, pickadate will try to load AMD modules, in my case we need commonjs, we don't want to change the code on the library, rather disable this 
using a rule (loader), just only for the pickadate folder:

`diff
  module: {
    rules: [
+      {
+        test: /pickadate/,
+        parser: { amd: false }
+      },

      {
        test: /\.ts$/,`

Now let's  review our provide plugin and ensure we have all this ways of global referencing jquery (window.jquery quite important !)

`diff
  plugins: [
+    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
+      "$": "jquery",
+      "jQuery": "jquery",
+      "window.jQuery": "jquery",

    }),`

It's time to start using this in our app, let's include it in the angular module where
we are using it (we are using angular 1.6):

```diff
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

export const LoginModule = angular.module('loginModule', 
+ ['pickadate'])
  .component('login', LoginComponent)
;
```

And let's use the directive in the HTML (input)

`diff
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtEmail">Birthdate</label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
+                                pick-a-date="vm.curDate"/>
                        </div>`

All this steps are just a recap of feedback got from several issues that were open, thanks to all the chaps that were providing the right tips :-). The parts that are new are marked with "+" (it seems stackoverflow doesn't support diff).