# How can pickadate be imported?

Tags: webpack, pickadate

How can [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) be imported using Webpack?

There seems to have been much discussion about this in the past (for instance: [this](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/870), [this](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/pull/779), [this](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/775), [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/struggling-to-load-pickadate-with-webpack), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863079/webpack-bower-multiple-css-js-files)). However, I could not identify any clear solution for how to reliably import pickadate using Webpack. Are there any good solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I found this best solution. In the webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: { 'picker': 'pickadate/lib/picker' }
},
```